# C# Input Director

Tags: c#

Im working on a simple program but i'm stuck. I've created small macro in Input Director program that writes some text to the file when certain keys are pressed. I started to write a simple c# program that invokes that keys but it seems that Input Director ignores this. this program works (if i will run it it simulates ctr+f  for example but Input Director dont catch this and don't input txt to the file.

Program :

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Console.Read();

        Thread.Sleep(1000);

        PressKey('x' , true);
        PressKey('x', false);

        Console.Read();
        Console.Read();

    }
    public static void PressKey(char ch, bool press)
    {
        byte vk = WindowsAPI.VkKeyScan(ch);
        ushort scanCode = (ushort)WindowsAPI.MapVirtualKey(vk, 0);

        if (press)
            KeyDown(scanCode, vk);
        else
            KeyUp(scanCode, vk);
    }

    public static void KeyDown(ushort scanCode, byte vk)
    {
        INPUT[] inputs = new INPUT[1];
        inputs[0].type = WindowsAPI.INPUT_KEYBOARD;
        inputs[0].ki.dwFlags = 0;
        inputs[0].ki.wScan = (ushort)(scanCode & 0xff);
        //inputs[0].ki.wVk = vk;

        uint intReturn = WindowsAPI.SendInput(1, inputs, System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.SizeOf(inputs[0]));
        if (intReturn != 1)
        {
            throw new Exception("Could not send key: " + scanCode);
        }
    }

    public static void KeyUp(ushort scanCode, byte vk)
    {
        INPUT[] inputs = new INPUT[1];
        inputs[0].type = WindowsAPI.INPUT_KEYBOARD;
        inputs[0].ki.wScan = scanCode;
        inputs[0].ki.dwFlags = WindowsAPI.KEYEVENTF_KEYUP | WindowsAPI.KEYEVENTF_SCANCODE;
        //inputs[0].ki.wVk = vk;
        uint intReturn = WindowsAPI.SendInput(1, inputs, System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.SizeOf(inputs[0]));
        if (intReturn != 1)
        {
            throw new Exception("Could not send key: " + scanCode);
        }
    }
}
```

Windows API :

```
 public class WindowsAPI
{
    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    public const uint WM_KEYDOWN = 0x100;

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    public const uint WM_KEYUP = 0x101;

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    public const uint WM_LBUTTONDOWN = 0x201;

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    public const uint WM_LBUTTONUP = 0x202;

    public const uint WM_CHAR = 0x102;

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    public const int MK_LBUTTON = 0x01;

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    public const int VK_RETURN = 0x0d;

    public const int VK_ESCAPE = 0x1b;

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    public const int VK_TAB = 0x09;

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    public const int VK_LEFT = 0x25;

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    public const int VK_UP = 0x26;

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    public const int VK_RIGHT = 0x27;

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    public const int VK_DOWN = 0x28;

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    public const int VK_F5 = 0x74;

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    public const int VK_F6 = 0x75;

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    public const int VK_F7 = 0x76;

    /// <summary>
    /// The GetForegroundWindow function returns a handle to the foreground window.
    /// </summary>
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    public static extern uint GetCurrentThreadId();

    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern uint GetWindowThreadProcessId(IntPtr hWnd, out uint lpdwProcessId);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern bool AttachThreadInput(uint idAttach, uint idAttachTo, bool fAttach);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern bool ReadProcessMemory(
      IntPtr hProcess,
      IntPtr lpBaseAddress,
      [Out()] byte[] lpBuffer,
      int dwSize,
      out int lpNumberOfBytesRead
     );

    public static void SwitchWindow(IntPtr windowHandle)
    {
        if (GetForegroundWindow() == windowHandle)
            return;

        IntPtr foregroundWindowHandle = GetForegroundWindow();
        uint currentThreadId = GetCurrentThreadId();
        uint temp;
        uint foregroundThreadId = GetWindowThreadProcessId(foregroundWindowHandle, out temp);
        AttachThreadInput(currentThreadId, foregroundThreadId, true);
        SetForegroundWindow(windowHandle);
        AttachThreadInput(currentThreadId, foregroundThreadId, false);

        while (GetForegroundWindow() != windowHandle)
        {
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="hwndParent"></param>
    /// <param name="hwndChildAfter"></param>
    /// <param name="lpszClass"></param>
    /// <param name="lpszWindow"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern IntPtr FindWindowEx(IntPtr hwndParent, IntPtr hwndChildAfter, string lpszClass, string lpszWindow);

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="hWnd"></param>
    /// <param name="msg"></param>
    /// <param name="wParam"></param>
    /// <param name="lParam"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    [DllImport("User32.Dll", EntryPoint = "PostMessageA")]
    public static extern bool PostMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint msg, int wParam, int lParam);

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="ch"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern byte VkKeyScan(char ch);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern uint MapVirtualKey(uint uCode, uint uMapType);

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="name"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static IntPtr FindWindow(string name)
    {
        Process[] procs = Process.GetProcesses();

        foreach (Process proc in procs)
        {
            if (proc.MainWindowTitle == name)
            {
                return proc.MainWindowHandle;
            }
        }

        return IntPtr.Zero;
    }

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr SetFocus(IntPtr hWnd);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    public static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="low"></param>
    /// <param name="high"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static int MakeLong(int low, int high)
    {
        return (high << 16) | (low & 0xffff);
    }

    [DllImport("User32.dll")]
    public static extern uint SendInput(uint numberOfInputs, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, SizeConst = 1)] INPUT[] input, int structSize); 

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr GetMessageExtraInfo();

    public const int INPUT_MOUSE = 0;
    public const int INPUT_KEYBOARD = 1;
    public const int INPUT_HARDWARE = 2;
    public const uint KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY = 0x0001;
    public const uint KEYEVENTF_KEYUP = 0x0002;
    public const uint KEYEVENTF_UNICODE = 0x0004;
    public const uint KEYEVENTF_SCANCODE = 0x0008;
    public const uint XBUTTON1 = 0x0001;
    public const uint XBUTTON2 = 0x0002;
    public const uint MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE = 0x0001;
    public const uint MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN = 0x0002;
    public const uint MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP = 0x0004;
    public const uint MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTDOWN = 0x0008;
    public const uint MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTUP = 0x0010;
    public const uint MOUSEEVENTF_MIDDLEDOWN = 0x0020;
    public const uint MOUSEEVENTF_MIDDLEUP = 0x0040;
    public const uint MOUSEEVENTF_XDOWN = 0x0080;
    public const uint MOUSEEVENTF_XUP = 0x0100;
    public const uint MOUSEEVENTF_WHEEL = 0x0800;
    public const uint MOUSEEVENTF_VIRTUALDESK = 0x4000;
    public const uint MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE = 0x8000;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct MOUSEINPUT
{
    int dx;
    int dy;
    uint mouseData;
    uint dwFlags;
    uint time;
    IntPtr dwExtraInfo;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct KEYBDINPUT
{
    public ushort wVk;
    public ushort wScan;
    public uint dwFlags;
    public uint time;
    public IntPtr dwExtraInfo;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct HARDWAREINPUT
{
    uint uMsg;
    ushort wParamL;
    ushort wParamH;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
public struct INPUT
{
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public int type;
    [FieldOffset(4)] //*
    public MOUSEINPUT mi;
    [FieldOffset(4)] //*
    public KEYBDINPUT ki;
    [FieldOffset(4)] //*
    public HARDWAREINPUT hi;
}
```

Edit :

My problem is that i'm trying to imitate keyboard key press by c# program. This should be intercepted by Input Director program (Software KVM to Control Multiple Computers) and this program should do something depending on the keys that are pressed by c# program. Now when i run c# program Input Director doesn't catch keyboard input that is done by c# and i don't know why i'm using low level SendInput Api so it should work.

Comment: What have you tried to fix your problem ? Please read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and edit your question.

Comment: Please explain the problem in more detail and include your expected behavior of the program. As it stands now it's unclear what you are asking for help on.